# Dynamodb batch write delete request does not work with partition and sort key

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Table overview:

```
ItemTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: Items
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: projectId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: addedTime
            KeyType: RANGE
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: projectId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: addedTime
            AttributeType: N
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.tableThroughput}
          WriteCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.tableThroughput}
        LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: idIndex
          KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: projectId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
```

I have a table where I want to perform batch write Request and delete all items from the table which has a particular projectId.

I fetch all the records having a particular projectId.
I loop over each item and create the params for batch write and do the query. which gives an error that the "The provided key element does not match the schema".

// Query to find all the records having a particular project Id.
// loop over each item

```
 params.RequestItems['Items'] = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < allRecordsWithSameProjectId.length; i++) {
          params.RequestItems['Items'].push({ DeleteRequest: {
            Key: { 
              projectId: allRecordsWithSameProjectId[i].projectId, 
              addedTime: allRecordsWithSameProjectId[i].addedTime
            }
          } 
        });
        }
    }
 let operationResult = await docClient.batchWrite(params).promise();
```

I found that both Hash and range key are required to delete the item. I am passing both but still getting the error.
Note: If I do single item delete query with both (projectId and addedTime) in key, the operation is successful.

Please help.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property) and confirmed that your `params` is valid?

Comment: This includes types, it looks like `projectId` is string and `addedTime` is number.

Comment: Yes, the params which are created for batchWrite operation have projectId as string and addedTime as number.

Comment: At a glance everything looks ok, would you be able to log and share the params of a bad request? I'm guessing that _one_ of your keys from the loop ends up with `projectId`/`addedTime` not being a string/number.